# nodejs npm throw error

Tags: node.js, npm

i just want to install node 5.0.0 by package. node can use, but npm can not use.

i don't know how to solve it.

```
Error: Cannot find module './lib'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:337:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:287:25)
at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
at require (module.js:385:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/node_modules/hawk/index.js:1:80)
at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:432:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
at require (module.js:385:17)
```

someone can help me ?

i list the error logs

```
npm ERR! Darwin 14.5.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm"
npm ERR! node v5.0.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.6
npm ERR! code MODULE_NOT_FOUND
npm ERR! Cannot find module './lib'
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See here for other people having this issue: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3606

Uninstalling nodejs by running:

```
rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
```

and reinstalling nodejs v5 seems to help.